# Core Data: filter many to may relationship with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I need to filter a many to many relationship. This means I have a third table for this connection.

```
Event <<- EventPlayerState ->> Player
```

I tried to find out if a Event already has the player connected via `EventPlayerState`.

The `EventPlayerState` table contains the attribute `isActive` to indicate if a player is active in the event.

I accessed the events relationship property `hasEventPlayerStates`. And tried to filter it with a `NSPredicate`. But it always returns false.

```
    NSPredicate *seachPlayerPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(hasPlayer = %@)", [player objectID]];

    NSSet *playerEventStates = [event hasPlayerEventStates];

    NSSet *filteredPlayer = [playerEventStates filteredSetUsingPredicate:seachPlayerPredicate];

    if([filteredPlayer count] == 1) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
```

What is wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not storing any additional information in your join table, that table to connect the two entities it is superfluous. You should then only have a many-to-many relationship between `Player` and `Event`.

The predicate is also much simpler:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"players.@count = 0"]
```

or to check for a particular Event

```
event.players.count == 0
```

In case you do need the join table, e.g because you are storing a timestamp or other information, it still looks sort of the same from the `Event`'s point of view.

The corresponding checks are exactly equivalent:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playerStates.@count = 0"]
event.playerStates.count == 0
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But I have additional attributes in the EventPlayerState. So your solution won't work. :)

Comment: What are they? Perhaps they are not necessary. Please include them in your question.

Comment: Actually, it does not make any difference. See my amended answer. The offered solutions should work as stated.

Comment: ok, I will try your solution. Currently I have a workaround in place which uses a attribute createdAt which contains the timestamp the entry was created. I don't think it's a good solution but it works.